# Am I a tenant in common by mortgaging my share?

Tags: united-kingdom, law

If I mortgage my share of the property and later pay off the mortgage, am I a joint tenant now or tenant in common?

Comment: What do you mean by "mortgage my share of the property"? Typically, a mortgage is applied to the whole of a property, since you can't repossess (foreclose on) half a house!

Comment: Its basically two person contributed to the house and they're registered as beneficial joint tenants. If one of them mortgage the part of his share of the house, he is now regarded as tenant in common. But what if he later pay off the mortgage? Is he now a joint tenant or tenant in common?

Comment: Do you have a reference for the claim that mortgaging turns you from a joint tenant to a tenant in common? That seems very surprising unless it's an explicit change you have to make as a condition of the mortgage (in which case the end of the mortgage would likely make no difference).

Comment: It appears that the reference is the Wikipedia article on [Concurrent Estate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_estate). As far as I'm aware, some of the details on that page don't apply in the UK; maybe it's talking about the US equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Responding also to the additional details from the OP's comment:*

In the UK, [you can't normally have a mortgage on a share of a property](http://hoa.org.uk/advice/guides-for-homeowners/i-am-buying/buying-a-home-with-a-partner-or-friend-what-to-watch-for/). Indeed, the lender generally doesn't care about the details of who owns what share.

Any mortgage will apply to the whole property, and will be in the name of **all** owners of the property, [with all those owners equally responsible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_and_several_liability), even if they own unequal shares.

Regarding [converting from a joint tenancy to a tenancy-in-common](https://www.gov.uk/joint-property-ownership/overview): there's nothing automatic about it. If you want to do that, you need a [declaration of trust](http://www.findlaw.co.uk/law/property/buying_property/500297.html) which states how big each owner's share is, and the Land Registry record must be updated.

Whatever you do, the lender still doesn't care.